# Dual-Boot with windows 7, ubuntu won't boot

Tags: dual-boot

I am new to linux and have been trying for a day now to get it installed, which i have, but it will not boot. When I turn on my pc, it boots straight to windows. I'm not sure what to do to fix this. I have tried using boot repair disk and this is what it came up with. http://paste.ubuntu.com/12865524/ .  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I installed ubuntu 15.04

Comment: @DnrDevil sorry,  what do you mean by "15.04 is not supported here" ?

Comment: You can aslo see questions to avoid here http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @DnrDevil I think you need to know about Ubuntu releases ,refer [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.04/) and [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Comment: @DnrDevil How exactly is 15.04 unsupported? It's not a development release and is under support until January 2016.

Comment: @DnrDevil how so? 15.04 is the latest current release

Comment: @DnrDevil and please use @ my name so I can know when you talk to me

Comment: @DnrDevil I downloaded ubuntu 15.04 from ubuntu's website, but I solved the problem. My BIOS had something called 2.2 Infinity enabled which wouldn't allow me to boot into Linux, but after I disabled it and reinstalled it worked great.